# Image.Canvas does'nt draw in my secondary procedure deplhi XE2

Tags: delphi, canvas

As you may see, it DOES draw the background (`BitMapRoad and BitMapGround`), yet it DOES NOT Draw the arry bitmap, to which a file was assigned (`Panzer[x]`). How can i fix it? Here's the full code:

```
 unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
       Winapi.Windows,Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

    type


      TFormGame = class(TForm)
        PanelGameMenu: TPanel;
        TimerSpawn: TTimer;
        TimerMove: TTimer;
        LabelWave: TLabel;
        LabelGold: TLabel;
        LabelLives: TLabel;
        ImageGround: TImage;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure OnGameClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        procedure TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
        procedure WaveStart;
        procedure TimerMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);




      private
        { Private declarations }


      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;


      var
      FormGame: TFormGame;
      PanzerImage:array[1..4] of TBitmap;
      Gun:array[1..2] of TBitmap;
      BitMapRoad,BitMapGround,BitmapNaziBase,BitmapSovjetBase,PanzerToRight,PanzerToLeft,PanzerToUp,PanzerToDown:TBitmap;
      WaveNumber,TCounter:integer;
      EnemyCounter,EC1:integer;
      PanzerFaust:array of TBitmap;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TFormGame.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);                                //процедура создания формы и инициализации рисунков
    var Counter1,Counter2,YY,yy2,hyy,x,y:integer;
    begin

    WaveNumber:=0;
    YY2:=150;                                                                       //инициализация
    YY:=50;
    HYY:=50;
    BitMapRoad:=TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapRoad.LoadFromFile('Road.bmp');
    BitMapGround:=TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapGround.LoadFromFile('Ground.bmp');
    BitMapNaziBase:=TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapNaziBase.LoadFromFile('NaziBase.bmp');
    BitMapSovjetBase:=TBitmap.Create;
    BitMapSovjetBase.LoadFromFile('SovjetBase.bmp');
    PanzerToUp:=TBitmap.Create;
    PanzerToUp.LoadFromFile('PanzerToUp.bmp');


    for counter1 := 1 to 20 do begin  {Начало цикла 1-го порядка}                   //создание травы
    for counter2:= 1 to 20 do begin {Начало цикла 2-го порядка}
    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(Counter1*50-50,Counter2*50-50,BitMapGround);
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}
    end;   {Конец цикла 1-го порядка}

    FormGame.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clBlack;
    FormGame.Canvas.Rectangle(50,50,100,100);


    for Counter1 := 1 to 5 do begin   {Начало цикла 1-го порядка}                   //создание спуска справа
    for Counter2 := 1 to 3 do begin   {Начало цикла 2-го порядка}
    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(950,yy,BitMapRoad);
    yy:=yy+50;
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}
    yy:=yy+50;
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}


    for Counter1 := 1 to 5 do begin   {Начало цикла 1-го порядка}                   //создание спуска слева
    for Counter2 := 1 to 3 do begin   {Начало цикла 2-го порядка}
    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,yy2,BitMapRoad);
    yy2:=yy2+50;
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}
    yy2:=yy2+50;
    end;   {Конец цикла 2-го порядка}

                                                                                    //создание горизонтальных дорог
    for Counter1 := 1 to 10 do begin
      for Counter2 := 1 to 20 do ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(Counter2*50-50,HYY,BitMapRoad);
    HYY:=HYY+100;
    end;

    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,050,BitmapNaziBase);
    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,950,BitmapSovjetBase);
    WaveStart;
    end;   {конец процедуры}                                                        //конец процедуры



    procedure TFormGame.OnGameClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    begin
    BitMapRoad.Free;
    BitMapGround.Free;
    BitMapSovjetBase.Free;
    BitMapNaziBase.Free;
    end;



    procedure TFormGame.TimerMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
    var counter:integer;
    begin
    for counter :=1 to EnemyCounter do begin


    end;
    end;

    procedure TFormGame.TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
    var counter:integer;
    begin
    TimerMove.Enabled:=true;
    if EC1<=EnemyCounter-1 then begin
    FormGame.Canvas.Draw(50,50,PanzerFaust[EC1]);
    EC1:=EC1+1;
    end;
    end;

    procedure TFormGame.WaveStart;
    var counter:integer;
    begin
    if WaveNumber<11 then begin
    SetLength(PanzerFaust,EnemyCounter);
    for counter:=  0 to EnemyCounter- 1 do begin
      PanzerFaust[Counter]:=TBitmap.Create;
      PanzerFaust[Counter].LoadFromFile('PanzerToRight.bmp');
    end;
      TimerSpawn.Enabled:=True;
      EC1:=1;
    end
    else ShowMessage('Фашистская Германия подписала акт о безоговорочной капитуляции');
    end;



    end.
```

As a result, i can not see it drawing in my timer procedure...

Comment: You are drawing to the form (not image) and using some global `EC1` - what is its value?

Comment: Well, i just corrected the drawing on form... that was a dull mistake, yet the' EC1' variable has its initialisation in the wavestart procedure. The thing is, it's still doing nothing...

Comment: This won't work. Draw in response to WM_PAINT. In event terms, draw in an OnPaint event.

Comment: But... how do i add this OnPaint event?

Comment: Like any other event. You've managed others. You are going to have to redesign your program to work in an event driven manner. And why, oh why, do you have all those global variables?

Comment: Thanks... I guess you are saving my life and my mind

Comment: Накатим за StackOverflow!

Comment: Раз так, значит до дна!